# How do I specify a time to display a SplashScreen in NetBeans VM Options?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, command-line-arguments, splash-screen

So I have it set to where it loads a splash screen on startup, now how do I specify how long to keep that splash screen there? In the `VM Options` textbox, I have the following code:

`-splash:src/myprojectname/splash.jpg`

How do I specify how long to keep it there?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will stay on the screen until your program succeeds in creating a new window. There is no time delay, you would insert that yourself by sleeping at the start of the program.

Comment: I had to wait for the time limit. Please be patient.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is right , `splash screen` will always run until next new window is not generated by compiler. But, Yeah it is in your hands you can delay the next window appearance by using these steps.

**1)** Go to next form which you want to show after `splash screen`.
**2)** Search for `main function`.
**3)** Inside `void run()` function just write these lines given below.

```
try
{ Thread.sleep(time in milliseconds); } catch {Exception e){
 }
```